# Concept of shared experience

Tags: social-psychology, philosophy-of-mind

Michael Stevens/VSauce summarized one aspect he realized after a 3 days isolation experiment as follows:

> .. being able to talk to people and share my experiences - I realized how
>   important that was.
>   **If you only have your own experiences, you are
>   not fully having them. You have to have someone else to listen to them
>   and react to them, and then you've fully experienced them**.

Ref: https://youtu.be/iqKdEhx-dD4?t=31m55s

Is there a name for this idea?

I guess this idea and related concepts have been postulated in social psychology or social philosophy before.

Comment: I had some problems tagging my question since I am new to this Q&A forum. So, please feel free to tag appropriately.

Comment: Clearly isolation does bad things to people.  Baek S. B. (2014). Psychopathology of social isolation. Journal of exercise rehabilitation, 10(3), 143–147. https://doi.org/10.12965/jer.140132